# Multi producer/consumer lock-free queue

Tags: c++, performance, multithreading, lock-free, producer-consumer

I would be grateful if you could review my code for a multi producer/consumer lock-free queue in C++.

I am mainly after performance improvements, but all input is welcome.

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <optional>
#include <cmath>

template<typename QueueItemT, size_t bufferSize>
class LockFreeQueue {

    using SleepGranularity = std::chrono::nanoseconds;

public:

    LockFreeQueue() = delete;

    /** A constructor which takes the total number of consumer+producer threads
     *  as argument. This will subsequently be used to define how many times a 
     *  thread will spin before going to sleep.
     * 
     *  If a custom spin count is provided, the number of threads is ignored and 
     *  the custom spin count is used, as is, instead.
     *
     *  @arg numberOfThreads - the total number of consumer+producer threads.
     *  @arg customSpinCount - the times a thread will spin before going to sleep.
     */
    LockFreeQueue(std::optional<size_t> numberOfThreads = std::nullopt,
                  std::optional<size_t> customSpinCount = std::nullopt)
    : sleepDurationStart{numberOfThreads.has_value()?-spinCount(*numberOfThreads):
                         customSpinCount.has_value()?*customSpinCount:
                         10} // If no number of threads or custom spin count was defined, we will default to a spin count of 10.
    {}

    ~LockFreeQueue() = default;

    // Make the queue non copyable.
    LockFreeQueue(const LockFreeQueue&) = delete;
    LockFreeQueue& operator=(const LockFreeQueue&) = delete;

    /** Push data into the queue.
     *
     *  The purpose of the "push" function is to push data into the queue.
     *
     *  If there is no space, the thread will return false and will not
     *  wait for space to become available.
     *
     *  However, once a space has been claimed, access to the queue is
     *  released and other threads can use the queue while the data is
     *  copied into the claimed space.
     *
     *  @arg bufferItem - the data to be pushed into the queue.
     */
    bool push(QueueItemT bufferItem) {

        size_t newTail{};
        bool keepTrying{ true };
        SleepGranularity sleepDuration{ sleepDurationStart };
        std::optional<size_t> pushIndex{ std::nullopt };

        _pendingData.fetch_add(2, std::memory_order_relaxed); // We are going to add data in the queue.
                                                              // We intentionally use 2 here in order to 
                                                              // also use the atomic to prevent memory 
                                                              // reordering in what follows.

        do
        {
            if (_canUpdate.exchange(false, std::memory_order_acquire)) { // Gain access and check index positions.

                newTail = (_tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1) % bufferSize; // Calculate the new tail

                if (newTail != _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) { // When _tail + 1 == _head we can not add.

                    if (!_isBusy.at(_tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)
                                         ).exchange(true, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { // Check that the index is not busy

                        pushIndex = _tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
                        _tail.store(newTail, std::memory_order_relaxed);

                        keepTrying = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    keepTrying = false;
                }

                _canUpdate.store(true, std::memory_order_release); // Allow access to the critical section for other 
                                                                   // threads to update the indexes
            }

            if (keepTrying) {
                sleepDuration = backOff(sleepDuration); // If we keep retrying, try not to overload the CPU
            }
        } while (keepTrying); // Do work until tail is updated and we can push the data

        if (pushIndex.has_value()) {

            _buffer.at(*pushIndex) = bufferItem;

            _pendingData.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel); // We succesfully pushed data. Decrement the counter to 
                                                                  // what it should be and also use the atomic to prevent 
                                                                  // memory reordering.
                                                                  // Use memory_order_acq_rel to prevent read/writes move.

            _isBusy.at(*pushIndex).store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed); // Flag that we are done with the index

            return true; // We succesfully placed the data in the queue.
        }

        _pendingData.fetch_sub(2, std::memory_order_relaxed); // We failed to add data in the queue.

        return false; // We did not have space to put the data into the queue.
    }

    /** Pop data from the queue.
     *
     *  The purpose of the "pop" function is to extract data from the queue.
     *
     *  The assigned thread will claim the space containing the next available
     *  data. If there is no data, the thread will return false and will not
     *  wait for data to become available.
     *
     *  However, once a space has been claimed, access to the queue is
     *  released and other threads can use the queue while the data is
     *  returned back to the caller.
     *
     *  @arg popedData - the location to put the extracted data into.
     *
     *  @return return true if there was data available to return back
     *          to the caller, otherwise return false.
     */
    bool pop(QueueItemT& popedData) {

        bool keepTrying{ true };
        SleepGranularity sleepDuration{ sleepDurationStart };
        std::optional<size_t> popIndex{ std::nullopt };

        do
        {
            if (_canUpdate.exchange(false, std::memory_order_acquire)) { // Gain access and check index positions.

                if (_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) !=
                    _tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) { // When head == tail we can not remove

                    if (!_isBusy.at(_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)
                                         ).exchange(true, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { // Check that the producer thread managed 
                                                                                        // to commit data to the _head index and the 
                                                                                        // index is now not busy.

                        popIndex = _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

                        _head.store((_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1) % bufferSize,
                            std::memory_order_relaxed); // Update the head;

                        keepTrying = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    keepTrying = false;
                }

                _canUpdate.store(true, std::memory_order_release); // Allow access to the critical section for other 
                                                                   // threads to update the indexes
            }

            if (keepTrying) {
                sleepDuration = backOff(sleepDuration); // If we keep retrying, try not to overload the CPU
            }
        } while (keepTrying); // Do work until head is updated and there is no more data to pop in the queue

        if (popIndex.has_value()) {

            popedData = _buffer.at(*popIndex);

            _pendingData.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel); // We removed data from the queue.
                                                                  // Use memory_order_acq_rel to prevent read/writes move.

            _isBusy.at(*popIndex).store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed); // Flag that we are done with the index

            return true; // We succesfully poped data.
        }

        return false; // There was no new data available.
    }

    /** Check if there is data in the queue.
     *
     * @return true if there is data in the queue, false otherwise.
     */
    bool hasData() {
        return _pendingData.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 0;
    }

private:
    /** Put the thread to sleep.
     *
     *  The purpose of the "backOff" function is to put the thread to sleep.
     *  The sleep duration increases linearly until a threashold is reached.
     *
     *  @arg sleepDuration - the current value of the sleep duration.
     *
     *  @return the updated value of the sleep duration
     */
    SleepGranularity backOff(SleepGranularity sleepDuration) {

        std::this_thread::yield();

        if (sleepDuration < sleepDurationStep) {

            return sleepDuration + sleepDurationStep;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleepDuration);

        return (sleepDuration < _maxSleepDuration)?
                    sleepDuration + sleepDurationStep: // increment the sleep duration if we are below the max threashhold
                    sleepDurationStart;                // otherwise reset the sleep duration to sleepDurationStart
    }

    /** Approximate spins.
     *
     *  The purpose of the "spinCount" function is to aproximate the 
     *  number of times a consumer/producer thread is going to spin 
     *  before going to sleep.
     *
     *  @arg numberOfThreads - total number of consumer+producer threads.
     *
     *  @return the number of times a consumer/producer thread is going 
     *          to spin before going to sleep.
     */
    int spinCount(size_t numberOfThreads) {
        return 86.404/std::pow(numberOfThreads, 0.691); // This is an approximation based on ~10million pops per 2 minutes 
                                                        // performance within reasonable CPU load. The approximation was 
                                                        // derived using a 4-core CPU. This approximation will probably need 
                                                        // to be re-evaluated based on the CPU cores.
    }

    std::array<QueueItemT, bufferSize> _buffer{}; // the ring buffer
    std::array<std::atomic_bool, bufferSize> _isBusy{ false }; // the buffer if there is work pending on each index
    std::atomic<size_t> _head{ 0 }; // consumer index
    std::atomic<size_t> _tail{ 0 }; // producer index
    std::atomic<long long> _pendingData{ 0 }; // count pending data in the queue
    std::atomic_bool _canUpdate{ true }; // critical section protection

    SleepGranularity sleepDurationStart{};   // the initial value of the sleepDuration. Adding sleepDurationStep, 
                                             // until it reaches 1, translates to how many times we are going to 
                                             // spin before going to sleep. eg, sleepDurationStart = -10 and 
                                             // sleepDurationStep = 1 => we are going to spin 10 times before 
                                             // going to sleep for some value of sleepDuration.

    SleepGranularity sleepDurationStep{ 1 }; // the value by which we increment sleepDurationStart every time we spin.
    SleepGranularity _maxSleepDuration{ 1 }; // the maximum time the thread can go to sleep for.
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is not lock-free

Unfortunately, your queue is not [lock-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom). Basically, your `_canUpdate` is used as a lock. Consider a thread that has taken the lock, so it's inside the `if`-statement that did the atomic exchange. Then, the operating system might suspend that thread for whatever reason. Other threads that want to push or pop items can now no longer progress.

Your locking strategy is possibly worse than a `std::mutex`. If you try to lock a `std::mutex`, it also does an atomic exchange to mark the mutex locked. If it was already locked by another thread, it will then make a system call to suspend the thread until the mutex is unlocked. In your case, you also do a system call when `_canUpdate` was already `false` via `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`. However, this waits either too short or too long. If it waits too long your queue's throughput is reduced, if it waits too short it is making multiple system calls that are wasting energy and reduce the amount of time for other threads to run on the same core.

Comment: Thank you for the wake-up call. If I update my code, can I update the question or should I make a new post instead?

Comment: You should make a new post instead. However, you can then add a link to the new question into this one.